# Download arbitrary file with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, download

Google Chrome starts downloading a file automatically after you click on a download link. However if this file is pdf or wmv then instead of downloading a file it opens it with browser's pdf reader (pdf) or plays it (wmv).

Can you force Chrome to just download an arbitrary file? I don't want to turn off the default behaviour altogether because most of the time it's what I want. But sometimes I want to download a file rather than to open it in a browser.

EDITED PART:
What when the url to a file I am interested in downloading comes from my windows clipboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the link and click "Save Link As..."

EDIT: To follow up on the need to download arbitrarily from clipboard, I would just create a generic HTML file and use the above solution. Save as mylink.html to file system somewhere. Open in Chrome.

```
<html>
<a href="http://www.mycompany.com/secretvideo.mp4">Link</a>
</html>
```

Comment: I was stupid of me to not make it clear that my real problem is a bit different (url is in the clipboard). I've just edited the question.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm sorry but I don't have much experience with how you would do this on Windows (On UNIX it is easy). So I can't really be much help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a free download manager such as [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.linksave.net/ and paste the URL, then right click on the link the site generates.

Before linksave.net my solution was to keep a tiny html file on my desktop that I could modify with the appropriate URL.